# How to fix 'jpy module has no attribute get_type' error while using jpy on mac?

Tags: python, import, module

Could anyone please help with a hint to resolve the error that I get while trying to use jpy;

I installed the module to site-packages to make it permanently available.
The build process was successful too. The build creates two folders; the first is 'build/' and it contains (among others) the jpy library for macOs 'lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6', and the second folder is 'dist/' that contains a wheel: 'jpy-0.10.0.dev1-cp36-cp36m-macosx_10_7_x86_64.whl'. I thought that I may be have to do something explicitly with these (?)
Thank you in advance.

```
import jpy

File = jpy.get_type('java.io.File')

file = File('test_jpy.py')

name = file.getName()

print(name)
```

Comment: What happens when you do `print(dir(jpy))`?

Comment: Actually, things changed a bit, yesterday i downloaded the .whl file from here 'https://github.com/bcdev/jpy/releases' and did: 'pip install the_package.whl', so now it's erroring on the import, saying that:
Library not loaded: @rpath/libjvm.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/fatima-zahra/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jpy.cpython-36m-darwin.so
  Reason: Incompatible library version: jpy.cpython-36m-darwin.so requires version 1.0.0 or later, but libjvm.dylib provides version 0.0.0
So I think, I can change the .whl I downloaded or see how to get the required version of the libjvm

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy, I -today- gave another 'libjvm' path (it seems I gave the wrong file at first), so I think the module is intalled, I get this after the print:
'['JException', 'JField', 'JMethod', 'JOverloadedMethod', 'JType', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', 'array', 'cast', 'create_jvm', 'destroy_jvm', 'diag', 'get_type', 'has_jvm', 'type_callbacks', 'types']'
but then, I get a runtime error : RuntimeError: jpy: No JVM available.

need to figure this out now! any help please?

Comment: Well, it seems that I skipped functions in jpy package that are for JVM creation (jpy.create_jvm(options)), but then when I fill the options with '-Djava.library.path=the_path', I get this: 'No Java runtime present, requesting install'; the stranger thing is that it's requiring me Java SE 6 !! in jpy website, it's said that: 'jpy has been tested with Python 2.7, 3.3, 3.4 and Oracle Java 7 and 8 JDKs. It will presumably also work with Python 2.6 or 3.2 and a Java 6 JDK.'  so I surely did something wrong :/

Comment: Well, I finally did the strange thing they were asking me to do, I just installed Java SE6 and it's working, I didnt even set JSE 6 as the default Java, but it's working, but I'm not sure if my programs (that are writtend in > JSE 7) will work! let's see..I hope so.

Comment: So got other problems but finally I could resovle it fully after so many days!! here is the configuration: after the imports... "jpyutil.init_jvm(java_home='/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/',jvm_dll='/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/server/libjvm.dylib',jvm_classpath=['user_project_bins'])", the trick is that the 'libjvm.dylib' should that of ../Home/lib/.. and not ..Home/jre/lib.. actually, I have (mandatory) openJDK 11.0.1 and it has a 'jre' directory, this was difficult to find out..

Comment: Actually, jdk 11.0.3 doesn't have a Home/jre/.. thanks to this only I could get from where the biggest error was coming. Does anyone have any idea why there is this directory in OpenJDK-11.0.1?